# How do you determine if an IP address is private, in Python?

Tags: python, network-programming, ip-address

In Python, what is the best way to determine if an IP address (e.g., `'127.0.0.1'` or `'10.98.76.6'`) is on a [private network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network)?  The code does not sound difficult to write.  But there may be more edge cases than are immediately apparent, and there's IPv6 support to consider, etc.  Is there an existing library that does it?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Check out the [IPy](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/IPy/) module. If has a function `iptype()` that seems to do what you want:

```
>>> from IPy import IP
>>> ip = IP('127.0.0.0/30')
>>> ip.iptype()
'PRIVATE'
```

Comment: As expected for a public IP, the string is 'PUBLIC'.  There are a few unexpected results: `print(IP('127.0.0.1').iptype())` yields `PRIVATE`.  `print(IP('::1').iptype())` yields `LOOPBACK`.  `print(IP('2001:0658:022a:cafe:0200::1').iptype())` yields `ALLOCATED RIPE NCC`

Comment: There are indeed a few unexpected results: `print(IP('0.0.0.0/0').iptype())` yields 'PRIVATE', while I'd expect "the whole IPv4 internet" to be PUBLIC...

Comment: Should I use it to prevent SSRF?

Comment: How are you intending to use it to prevent SSRF ?

Answer (score 92):

Since Python 3.3 there is an [ipaddress module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html) in the stdlib that you can use.

```
>>> import ipaddress
>>> ipaddress.ip_address('192.168.0.1').is_private
True
```

If using Python 2.6 or higher I would strongly recommend to use [a backport of this module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/py2-ipaddress/).

Answer (score 26):

You can check that yourself using
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1918 and https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3330. If you have 127.0.0.1 you just need to `&` it with the mask (lets say `255.0.0.0`) and see if the value matches any of the private network's [network address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address). So using [inet_pton](http://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.inet_pton) you can do: `127.0.0.1 & 255.0.0.0 = 127.0.0.0`

Here is the code that illustrates that:

```
from struct import unpack
from socket import AF_INET, inet_pton

def lookup(ip):
    f = unpack('!I',inet_pton(AF_INET,ip))[0]
    private = (
        [ 2130706432, 4278190080 ], # 127.0.0.0,   255.0.0.0   https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3330
        [ 3232235520, 4294901760 ], # 192.168.0.0, 255.255.0.0 https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1918
        [ 2886729728, 4293918720 ], # 172.16.0.0,  255.240.0.0 https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1918
        [ 167772160,  4278190080 ], # 10.0.0.0,    255.0.0.0   https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1918
    ) 
    for net in private:
        if (f & net[1]) == net[0]:
            return True
    return False

# example
print(lookup("127.0.0.1"))
print(lookup("192.168.10.1"))
print(lookup("10.10.10.10"))
print(lookup("172.17.255.255"))
# outputs True True True True
```

another implementation is to compute the int values of all private blocks:

```
from struct import unpack
from socket import AF_INET, inet_pton

lookup = "127.0.0.1"
f = unpack('!I',inet_pton(AF_INET,lookup))[0]
private = (["127.0.0.0","255.0.0.0"],["192.168.0.0","255.255.0.0"],["172.16.0.0","255.240.0.0"],["10.0.0.0","255.0.0.0"])
for net in private:
    mask = unpack('!I',inet_aton(net[1]))[0]
    p = unpack('!I',inet_aton(net[0]))[0]
    if (f & mask) == p:
        print lookup + " is private"
```

Answer (score 10):

This is the fixed version of the regex approach suggested by @Kurt including the fix recommended by @RobEvans

- ^127.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}$
- ^10.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}$
- ^192.168.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}$
- ^172.(1[6-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-1]).[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}$

  ```
   def is_ip_private(ip):

       # https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network

       priv_lo = re.compile("^127\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}$")
       priv_24 = re.compile("^10\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}$")
       priv_20 = re.compile("^192\.168\.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}$")
       priv_16 = re.compile("^172.(1[6-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-1]).[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}$")

       res = priv_lo.match(ip) or priv_24.match(ip) or priv_20.match(ip) or priv_16.match(ip)
       return res is not None
  ```

This will not 100.x.x.x range which is used internally in kubernetes

Comment: +1, I'd suggest returning a boolean "wrapper", to better reflect the function name:
return (priv_lo.match(ip) or priv_24.match(ip) or priv_20.match(ip) or priv_16.match(ip)) is not None

Answer (score 2):

A few days after asking this question, I found out about this Google project, [ipaddr-py](http://code.google.com/p/ipaddr-py/source/browse/trunk/ipaddr.py), which appears to have some of the same functionality with respect to determining if an address is private (`is_rfc1918`).  Apparently this will be standard in Python 3.1.

Comment: It is provisional in 3.3 now, see the [ipaddress][1] module.

  [1]: http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/ipaddress.html

Comment: See the "is_private" property.

Answer (score 2):

I find this in [cuckoo](https://github.com/wmetcalf/cuckoo-master/blob/master/modules/processing/network.py).There is no need to install new modules.Just import two built-in modules: socket and struct. And use function below.

```
def _is_private_ip(self, ip):
    """Check if the IP belongs to private network blocks.
    @param ip: IP address to verify.
    @return: boolean representing whether the IP belongs or not to
             a private network block.
    """
    networks = [
        "0.0.0.0/8",
        "10.0.0.0/8",
        "100.64.0.0/10",
        "127.0.0.0/8",
        "169.254.0.0/16",
        "172.16.0.0/12",
        "192.0.0.0/24",
        "192.0.2.0/24",
        "192.88.99.0/24",
        "192.168.0.0/16",
        "198.18.0.0/15",
        "198.51.100.0/24",
        "203.0.113.0/24",
        "240.0.0.0/4",
        "255.255.255.255/32",
        "224.0.0.0/4",
    ]

    for network in networks:
        try:
            ipaddr = struct.unpack(">I", socket.inet_aton(ip))[0]

            netaddr, bits = network.split("/")

            network_low = struct.unpack(">I", socket.inet_aton(netaddr))[0]
            network_high = network_low | 1 << (32 - int(bits)) - 1

            if ipaddr <= network_high and ipaddr >= network_low:
                return True
        except Exception,err:
            continue

    return False
```

Comment: this check fails example if ip : 172.29.0.1

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid importing a module you can just apply a simple regex:

- ^127.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}$
- ^10.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}$
- ^192.168.\d{1,3}$
- ^172.(1[6-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-1]).[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}$

Comment: Shouldn't those . characters be escaped via \. ? I guess the pattern will still work either way though.

Comment: That regex did not work for me, but if you substitute {123} by {1,3} it works fine.

Comment: I beg to disagree - it might work, but it's not simple. if I look at all these special characters and such, the term "simple" as I understand it doesn't apply to that regex... can you read, memorize it quickly and write it down again without looking at it(and without reconstructing it by the rules you applied)? Can you see at a glance if something is wrong / changed? So, IMHO yes, if you have reasons or constraints that make adding external code impossible/unwanted it works, but it's a complex and hard to debug/understand/memorize/verify expression.