# Python3 Wrong IP Address Detection?

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, ip, ip-address

Reading this:

[How do you determine if an IP address is private, in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/691045/how-do-you-determine-if-an-ip-address-is-private-in-python)

I wrote:

```
>>> import ipaddress
>>> ipaddress.ip_address('172.23.86.32').is_private
True
```

But that's not correct, this is a public IP address... how to fix  this?

Comment: The address is indeed a private address according to the [IANA IPv4 Special-Purpose Address Registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/iana-ipv4-special-registry/iana-ipv4-special-registry.xhtml). You can also look at [RFC 1918](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1918.html) that defines the rule for private networks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program is actually correct, 172.23.86.32 is a private IP address. Just check https://www.whatismyip.com/ or a similar service and you will see a different address (and that's your public address).

See this wiki entry on IPv4 private network addresses:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network#Private_IPv4_addresses

Comment: In my work we have devices and each device has IP like (10.0.0.32) and External Access like (172.23.86.32). If they are both private then what's the differenece

Comment: @Dan: For some reason the network admin put those devices on a separate private network and put it behind NAT (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation). Ask the admin(s) about why they did it.